# Tomcat 7 (when a servlet project) is included is not staring within 45 seconds...and increasing the timeout does not solve

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, timeout

Tomcat 7 is not starting when a web application(with a servlet) is attempted to run.The server works well when i only have a html page.But when i try to add a servlet and add it to tomcat.Then the server does not start and gives an error saying "Tomcat 7 didn't start in 45 seconds". I increased the timeout but nothing happened.Please help me solve this problem

The Console says :

```
"23 Jan, 2012 1:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in                  production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_23/jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_23/jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_23/jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin;F:\SOFTWARES\Eclipse Indigo\eclipse;
23 Jan, 2012 1:43:44 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property     'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Basic' did not find a matching property.
23 Jan, 2012 1:43:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
23 Jan, 2012 1:43:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-9999"]
23 Jan, 2012 1:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 717 ms
23 Jan, 2012 1:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
23 Jan, 2012 1:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.23
23 Jan, 2012 1:43:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component     [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Basic]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1100)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:782)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:674)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component     [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Basic]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Simple : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class Simple)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2827)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1655)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:58)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:338)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:831)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5148)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
23 Jan, 2012 1:43:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to     start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1100)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:624)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:623)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:674)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:782)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
23 Jan, 2012 1:43:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8000]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:624)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:623)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component         [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more
23 Jan, 2012 1:43:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 313 ms "    '
```

Comment: The space here is too small for my Console...plzz tell me where i can post that. One of the errors is "SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Basic]]"

Comment: You should be able to edit your question, AFAIK.

Comment: I have copied the whole console from Eclipse so that the problem may be figured out easily.  Please solve this 45s timeout problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you just copied the error message of the cause of the exception into Google, you would have found the problem. *"Unsupported major.minor version 51.0"* means that you compiled the classes with JDK7, but try to deploy and run it with a previous version of the JDK or JRE. Start your tomcat with JDK7, or change the JDK you're using to compile your classes.

Side note: your class seems to be named Simple and to be in the default package. This ie a bad practice that will cause all sorts of problems. Always put your classes in a package.

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration in the file servers.xml in the Package Explorer under Servers in Eclipse.
When you open this file in Design-mode, you can see the different Contexts-configs.
For you start there should be an entry. Check this Context entry: the docBase, path and source should refer to your project.